# What can I do about my question when no one views my question?

Tags: support

I asked this question [two days ago](https://superuser.com/questions/744939/how-can-i-add-messages-to-selfcontrols-whitelist), and I just got no responses, what can I do? I can't afford another bounty.

Some backgrounds: I really don't know too much about programming or OS X. So maybe I can't edit this question.

Comment: In that specific case maybe stackoverflow.com or apple.stackexchange.com are better suited

Answer (score 4):

If you can't further improve your question, and you can't afford to put a bounty on it, then you're really only left with one possible option:

Solve the problem yourself and then share what you've learned through an answer on your own question.

Comment: Technically, yes. In theory, no. I don't even understand objective-C.

Comment: At one point in my life, I didn't understand Objective-C either

Comment: Or, you could just let it go and earn a Tumbleweed badge before trying to get attention to it, during which time you can earn some more rep to place a bounty once you have earned the badge.

Comment: Tumbleweed badge -- the scarlet letter of SuperUser.